# I want to convert KeyValuePair to TreeView in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, json.net

I'm checking **IF File EXIST.**

```
if (File.Exists("Accounts.txt"))
        {
            string jsonToRead = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Accounts.txt"));
            vals =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(jsonToRead);
        }
```

then I **add my accounts**

```
account = Account_No;
        vals.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Bank_Names, account));
        AccountsComboBox2.Items.Add(account);
```

and **save the accounts**

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Accounts.txt")))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vals);
            sw.Write(json);
        }
```

when the application reloads, I want the accounts to display in Treeview.

I tried doing this but no help.

```
if (File.Exists("Accounts.txt"))
            {
                string treeView = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Accounts.txt"));
```

// ACCOUNTS.TXT FILE is saved with keyvaluepair, I want to convert KeyValuePair to TreeView where KEY is Parent Node and Value is it's sub-node.

```
                vals =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(TreeView);

TreeNode tree = (TreeNode)vals;


            }
```

**How I'm repopulating Treeview if the data is not in treeview?**

Answer to is this:

Parent Nodes are in bank comboBox that I'm adding to Treeview dynamically on run-time.

```
string[] items = new string[BankList.Items.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < BankList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                items[i] = BankList.Items[i].ToString();
                node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(items[i]);
            }
```

**when I add new account I'm saving data to key value pair as well as displaying in tree view**

Like this:

```
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(AccountNotextBox1.Text);
        //this is name
        newNode.Name = AccountNotextBox1.Text;
        //this is tag
        newNode.Tag = AccountNotextBox1.Text;
        treeView1.Nodes[BankList.SelectedIndex].Nodes.Add(newNode);
```

I'm saving data in keyvalue pair in Accounts.txt and saving treeview state in a seperate file name "Tree.txt" on form closing I wrote this code.

```
private void AccountsSetup_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
         SaveTree(treeView1, "Tree.txt");
    }
```

**On account Form Loading**

```
LoadTree(treeView1, "tree.txt");
```

Bank and it's account data is being saved in key-value pair file name accounts.txt and reloaded back when app starts.

and treeview state is saved in tree.txt when the new account is added.

I have to save this in 1 more seperate file.

> my question here is why can't I convert KeyValuePair back to TreeNode
>   and use the already saved data instead of saving the tree state in a
>   textfile on a user computer, it is not so professional, either the
>   state should be in application settings or somewhere where the user
>   doesn't have to worry about backing up treeview otherwise if this file
>   gets deleted.

comboBoxes will be showing data from keyValuePair saved in Accounts.txt.

but treeview will be empty only showing dynamic Bank Lists as parent nodes.

[image]

**Let say "Tree.txt" file gets deleted, this is what will happen.** 
Tree State is gone, but there are accounts there.

[image]

Comment: If I combine this question with your previous question, I would say you take the wrong approach to do these tasks. Why would you do all the work to read nodes and child nodes themselves to save them an load them ? Since the nodes exist based on a Bank with accounts, you should save the bank objects and repopulate the treeview based on the bank objects with there accounts.

Comment: My first approach is that I'm saving bank and accounts with key-value pair, after that I thought it should have tree as well to display properly, now I'm saying if the data is already saved in keyvalue pair, why not use the already saved data for reloading them to show treeview. Your suggestions are welcome, show me a better approach and I will add it in my system.

Comment: Well you should not take a Treeview as your "data" container. Thats where custom objects comes in. e.g. a Bank object that has a list of accounts. The Treeview is a display or select control, it's not designed to "hold" data, it's designed to represent data.

Comment: But I'm not holding data in treeview, data is in KeyValuePair and added to textfile name Accounts.txt, when I open my app I read the accounts.txt deserialize it back to keyvalue pair and display it in comboBoxes. I'm just saying in order to show the data in treeview, the key value pair data that is saved in textfile should be converted into treeview to display in treeview.

Comment: If the Treeview is not holding the data as you say. How do you populated the Treeview then before from the KeyValuePair ?

Comment: @jim good question. I'm editing my question to explain you.

Comment: Is this question still in need of an answer, or have you answered it within the question?  If the later, rather than including the answer in the question, can you please [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others can know that the issue is resolved?

Comment: yes this question is still in need of an answer.